# how to sum 1 row on operation of subquery in union

Tags: mysql, sql

hy, help me guys,
I want to **do the sum on the WIP column**, but I don't know how.

WIP column is **the operation of subtracting the input column by the output column**

The following is a screenshot of my operating results table:

[image]

*This is the query I use:*

```
SET @orc ='G3-21F034-1';


SELECT 
 c.size AS size,
 c.qty AS `order`,
 IF(EXISTS(SELECT ic1.size FROM input_cutting ic1 WHERE ic1.size=ic.size),ic.qty,'0') AS input,
 IFNULL(oc.qty,'0') AS output,
IF(oc.qty IS NULL, 'belum dimulai',IF( ic.qty-oc.qty >0, 'kurang', IF (ic.qty-oc.qty < 0, 'sisa','cukup'))) AS produksi,
 IFNULL(ABS(ic.qty-oc.qty),ic.qty) AS WIP
FROM
(SELECT
  ic.orc,
  ic.size as size,
  SUM(ic.qty_pcs) AS qty
FROM input_cutting ic
WHERE ic.orc=@orc
  GROUP BY size) AS ic
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
  oc.orc,
  oc.size AS size,
  SUM(oc.qty_pcs) AS qty
FROM output_cutting oc
WHERE oc.orc= @orc
GROUP BY size) AS oc ON ic.size=oc.size
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
    c.orc,cd.id_cutting, cd.size, cd.qty,
    MAX(IF(cd.outermold_barcode IS NULL, '0', '1')) AS `outer`,
    MAX(IF(cd.midmold_barcode IS NULL, '0', '1')) AS `mid`,
    MAX(IF(cd.linningmold_barcode IS NULL, '0', '1') ) AS `linning`
  FROM
    cutting c join cutting_detail cd ON c.id_cutting=cd.id_cutting
  WHERE
    c.orc=@orc
  GROUP BY
    cd.id_cutting) AS c ON c.size=ic.size

GROUP BY size
```

above is the first sql query, below is the second query combined with union

```
  UNION ALL

  SELECT
  'Total',
   c.qty AS `order`,
   SUM(ic.qty) AS inputTot,
   IFNULL(oc.qty,'0') AS outputTot,
   IF(oc.qty IS null,'BELUM MULAI DIPRODUKSI',IF ( ic.qty-oc.qty >0, 'KURANG', IF (ic.qty-oc.qty < 0, 'SISA','TERPENUHI'))) AS produksi,
   
  '???' AS WIPtot <------------------------ *summation operation here*
  
  FROM
(SELECT
  ic.orc,
  ic.size as size,
  SUM(ic.qty_pcs) AS qty
FROM input_cutting ic
WHERE ic.orc= @orc) AS ic LEFT JOIN
(SELECT
  oc.orc,
  oc.size AS size,
  SUM(oc.qty_pcs) AS qty
FROM output_cutting oc
WHERE oc.orc= @orc) AS oc ON ic.size=oc.size,
(SELECT 
  c.orc,cd.id_cutting, c.qty
FROM
  cutting c join cutting_detail cd ON c.id_cutting=cd.id_cutting
  WHERE
    c.orc='G3-21F034-1'
GROUP BY
  c.orc) AS c
```

- *that is my sql query, help me to solve that*

Comment: Use `rollup` to generate totals.

Comment: Your query is malformed and should be generating an error, because the `group by` columns are incompatible with the `select` columns.  You are either using an old version of MySQL or you have fiddled with the system settings on a more recent version.